# Is it possible to wrap text around the top and bottom of multiple images in css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is the kind of magazine style effect I am looking to recreate:

[image]

Using floats I seem only to be able to achieve text flowing underneath.

Using `shape-outside` I seem to be only able to use one shape per div of text at a time. Ideally I would be using multiple against the same div.

I have also tried using css grid, trying something to this effect to wrap text around the top and bottom of just one image:

```css
.mygrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "para para"
        "image para"
        "para para";
}


.lorem {
    background-color: red;
    grid-area: para;
}

.image {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: image;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
        <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
        <div class="im">I'm the image!</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your html plz?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you look for is a typical float use. *Grid is not yet able to do these kind of things, flowing text through different grid cell*

example

```css
.l{float:left;}
.r{float:right}

/* demo */
img{padding: .25em .25em 0;}
p{width:400px;border:solid;margin:1em auto;}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<img class="l" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50"> Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui.<img class="r" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50"> Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

From your code you posted, dropping the grid system and using float instead, an option could be : (setting image ahead in the flow)

```css
.mygrid {
  width:300px;
}
.mygrid:before {
  height:150px;
  float:left;
  content:''
}
.im{
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:gray;
  display:grid;
  align-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}

/* 2 images ? */

body{
display:flex;justify-content:space-between;
}
.im~.im {float:right;}
.mygrid+.mygrid .im {background:silver}
.lorem:before{
  content:'';
  float:left;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="im">I'm the image!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>

</div>

<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="im">I'm the image!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="im">I'm the image!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsam, iure facilis optio eum dignissimos. Quis aliquam inventore a sit quo est ut voluptas nesciunt iure, veniam consequuntur! Error, recusandae!</div>

</div>
```